# How to run a specified bat file at particular time ie.. scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been using the at command to schedule the task

```
ex: at 14:45 my.bat
```

and i am getting the o/p on the command prompt as

```
"JOB ID is added"
```

But this command is not getting fired on the time which i have scheduled..

Can anyone please help me.......

Comment: How do you know that the job is not execute? Does the batch file work correctly when it is called on its own? Are there any directory dependencies? Does the batch job need any permissions?

Comment: When i run normally without the scheduler im able to run the bat file... but when i am trying to run with the scheduler im not able to get the output....

By the way i think that the bat while on which im planning to do scheduling, the admin is not able to run...
So can u pls let me know the procedure how to make my bat file to be executable by admin..... pls pls......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is *not* that the BAT file is not executing at all, but rather either or both of i) individual commands within the BAT file are failing, or ii) the output isn't getting sent to the place you're looking for it. (Things get even weirder if anything in the batch file requests input, since a) by default batch files may not be able to interact with the "console" at all and b) the system is probably unattended anyway at the time the batch file executes.) If my suspicion is right, there is no *one* "fix-everything" but rather a whole bunch of small fixes  ...and you have to hit every one of them.

Find out the needed password to actually login as 'admin' (rather than your usual user), open a DOS box, and try to run the batch file. There should be some sort of error message that you can see. Fix that problem. Then try again  ...and fix the next problem. Keep correcting problems and trying again until finally everything works.